Windows firewall blocking IIS FTP connection - FTP port rules enabled
I've setup a Windows FTP server using IIS. The firewall port rules have been setup and enabled automatically during FTP installation, allowing FTP traffic on ports 21, 1024-65535 and 990.

When I try to connect from the server that the FTP server is running on, I can connect successfully with no issues.
However, when I try to connect to the FTP server from a computer on the network, the connection times out, if I disable the firewall, I can then connect successfully.
I am testing the FTP connection using PowerShell.

I deleted and recreated the existing firewall rules which were created automatically during FTP server installation, which allowed a successful connection.
The only difference I can see is that the 'Program' setting is now set to 'Any'.
